# How is shard number related with tagging an event in lagom?

Tags: scala, microservices, sharding, event-sourcing, lagom

Q1. Is it so that every event gets different sharded number?
Q2. What if there are 3 shards but only one event, then is it so that it will be sharded into one of the three? What about the leftover 2 shards, isn't it now redundant?
Q3. Even if events are sharded with different tags in different shards, how does order is maintained?

```
    eg. say events are as follows -

    UserCreated-3
    ProductAdded-2
    ProductAdded-1
    UserCreated-2
    UserCreated-1

    Now it is sharded into two -

In shard -1 say,
    UserCreated-3
    UserCreated-2
    UserCreated-1

In shard-2, say
    ProductAdded-2
    ProductAdded-1
```

Now, At some point they will be merged, then how the order is maintained?

Answer (score 1):

Lagom uses Akka Persistence tags to achieve Journal Sharding which allows for multiple read-side processors to work in parallel over a single journal.

How this works is this:

1. an instance of a persistent entity will tag all its events using the same shard identifier so all events of a single entity are read in the correct order
2. events from different entities may be processed out of order because events of `User-A` and events of `User-B` may be processed by different instance of a read-side processor

If you need absolute ordering of events you must not use event sharding and, instead, use a single tagger. The problem there is you'll loose throughput on your read-side processors since only a single instance will be created.